# The smell of the shield bug (aka stink bug)

Tags: species-identification, zoology, entomology, odour

Every time a shield bug flies into my room I try to kill it. Unfortunately, they leave a strong smell after crushing them. Whenever I smell their odor, I always wonder what  the chemical compound is that the bug releases. Does anyone know what the smelly chemical is? If so, please help me out. I always wanted to know what that molecule was.

Comment: [is this helpful?](http://www.aiche.org/chenected/2010/10/what-stinks)

Comment: bed bugs also have a very bad smell.

Comment: Some-how this question is locked for edit. (How?) . However tag add suggestion "identification" because this question basically seeking identification of a compound.

Comment: how did you locked your post from further edit? would you like to tell? however I wish keep my posts open to edit as per community guidelines, since all the edits yet done on my posts yet, were helpful to me.

Comment: If you don't like the smell,  you could always try to not kill it. Let it find it's own way out or help it on it's way with a glass and a piece of paper.

Comment: If an edit is already made and has not been approved then no further edits are allowed until the edit is approved/disapproved. @AlwaysConfused

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Shield bugs (also known as stink bugs) are a group of insects in the superfamily [Pentatomoidea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentatomoidea). As summarized by [this article](http://insectbio.rice.edu/2013/12/02/stink-stank-stunk-a-closer-look-at-the-chemical-defense-of-stink-bugs/) from Rice University, the components of the chemical odor of these insects **consist primarily of long chain alkanes, aldehydes, and esters.** Esters are to be expected as they're the primary components of many odors. This article also includes other ecological info about the shield bugs' stink, as well as links to some references (including [this](https://naldc.nal.usda.gov/download/24813/PDF) peer reviewed journal article by Krall et all (1999)).

[Another](http://www.aiche.org/chenected/2010/10/what-stinks) article mentions a 2006 study from Clemson University that identified 2 of the aldehydes in stink bug odor as trans-2-decenal and trans-2-octenal.